# Protractor Chained Element Confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, protractor

I'm trying to create a protractor test that uses a third party component from Cloudinary. I've so far been unsuccessful finding an element.

The HTML looks like this:

```html
<div class="header" id="cloudinary-navbar">
  <ul class="sources clear">
    <li class="source local active" data-source="local">
      <span class="label" data-text-key="sources.local.title">My files</span>
      <span class="icon"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="source url" data-source="url">
      <span class="label" data-text-key="sources.url.title">Web Address</span>
      <span class="icon"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="source camera" data-source="camera">
      <span class="label" data-text-key="sources.camera.title">Camera</span>
      <span class="icon"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to find the second `li` and doing this:

```
var webLinkButton = element(by.id('cloudinary-navbar')).element(by.css('.url'));
```

I get the following error:

```
Message:
    Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="cloudinary-navbar"])
  Stack:
    NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="cloudinary-navbar"])
```

That's confusing to me because I'm not searching for `cloudinary-navbar` by CSS.

How should I approach finding this element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="cloudinary-navbar"])

`*[id="your_id"]` is what [`WebDriverJS` actually uses](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/fd366029858cbb24bed40cab400af0062d04c2b9/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/test/lib/webdriver_test.js#L1166) to perform "by id" lookups.

In your case, this should not be relevant since the locator itself is correct and the element should be found. These are the common reasons for your "Element not found" problem:

- the element is *inside an `iframe`* and you need to switch to it:

  ```
  browser.switchTo().frame("frame_name_or_id");
  ```
- you need to *wait for the element to be present*, explicitly:

  ```
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id('cloudinary-navbar'))), 5000);
  ```
- element is not actually present, you need to make an extra action for it to appear - open up a menu, for instance

Comment: You're, right: I didn't notice that an iframe was created by the widget. I ended up using `switchTo().frame(0)` because I couldn't find any better selectors. I also used `switchTo().defaultContent()` to switch back. Thanks!